# How to show dynamic content in @angular/google-maps infoWindow

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-material

Specifically, how do you show information related to the marker in the respective infoWindow?

By following the example on the repo [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/google-maps/README.md), the same information is opened for every marker. With the old angular google maps you could easily just insert the info window inside the marker with whatever data you wanted.

I saw a few examples of setting the content with {{ contentHere }} in the template, but that only allows for strings. I need to use all the angular template stuff like usual.

Let's say our template looks something like the repo example:

```
<google-map height="400px"
        width="750px"
        [center]="center"
        [zoom]="zoom">
  <map-marker #marker
          *ngFor="let place of places"
          [position]="{ lat: place.latitude, lng: place.longitude }"
          [options]="markerOptions"
          (mapClick)="openInfoWindow(marker)">

      <map-info-window>
        <-- this is what i'm concerned with -->
        {{ place.description }}
      </map-info-window>
  </map-marker>
</google-map>
```

And then we add viewchild like the repo example and open it in the same way:

```
@ViewChild(MapInfoWindow, {static: false}) infoWindow: MapInfoWindow;

openInfoWindow(marker: MapMarker) {
  this.infoWindow.open(marker);
}
```

Although this does open the correct marker and the marker will reflect dynamic info, this will show the same content / place.description for every info window, which isn't really surprising since a single ViewChild is being used. I've come up with all kinds of convoluted ways to do this and had a look through the source code but there doesn't seem to be an obvious and/or built in solution for displaying content in the window that is related to what is being used by the marker. It just seems weird to not have that as a basic example.

How would any of you go about doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use ViewChildren, use index in the for loop in the template, pass in the index when marker is clicked, loop through all ViewChildren using an index inside of a forEach (for loop with index will not open the window for some reason), then if the index of the loop matches the index passed in, open that window. It seems like there would be a better way than this but it's all I could come up with after trying many things:

In component:

```
@ViewChildren(MapInfoWindow) infoWindowsView: QueryList<MapInfoWindow>;

openInfoWindow(marker: MapMarker, windowIndex: number) {
  /// stores the current index in forEach
  let curIdx = 0;
  this.infoWindowsView.forEach((window: MapInfoWindow) => {
    if (windowIndex === curIdx) {
      window.open(marker);
      curIdx++;
    } else {
      curIdx++;
    }
  });
}
```

In template:

```
<google-map height="400px"
    width="750px"
    [center]="center"
    [zoom]="zoom">
  <map-marker #marker
      *ngFor="let place of places; let i = index" <-- added index -->
      [position]="{ lat: place.latitude, lng: place.longitude }"
      [options]="markerOptions"
      (mapClick)="openInfoWindow(marker, i)"> <-- pass in index -->

      <map-info-window>
        {{ place.description }}
      </map-info-window>
  </map-marker>
</google-map>
```

This will open the info window with its respective marker.

Comment: How to pass evaluatable HTML template (as @Input parameter?) serving as an Info Window's markup into Angular component which creates Google Map dynamically?

Comment: curIdx++; in both if-else branches is redundant here; you don't need the 'else' part

Answer (score 13):

Simplest way, hope it can help

TS

```
public openInfoWindow(marker: MapMarker, infoWindow: MapInfoWindow) {
    infoWindow.open(marker);
}
```

HTML

```
<google-map *ngIf="mapOptions.center" width="100%" height="100%" [options]="mapOptions">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let elem of elements">
        <map-marker #marker="mapMarker" [position]="elem.position" [options]="elem.markerOptions" (mapClick)="openInfoWindow(marker, infoWindow)"></map-marker>
        <map-info-window #infoWindow="mapInfoWindow"> Content of {{ elem.id }} ...</map-info-window>
    </ng-container>
</google-map>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The `#infoWindow` template reference points to the DOM element instead of the `MapInfoWindow` component, so `infoWindow.open(...)` will error out with the `TypeError: infoWindow.open is not a function` error message.

Answer (score 6):

Most answers here are incorrect. Either

1. They're buggy by not passing type-checking (hashed ids point to HTML
   elements, not of MapMarker type, furthermore they are not unique as
   included in *ngFor loop) or
2. Have bad impact on performance (you
   don't need as many InfoWindows as MapMarkers, one is enough).

What I like most is the solution [Warren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11339017/warren-dowey) has proposed. My concept is similar and **as simple as that**:

**TS**

```
@ViewChild(MapInfoWindow, { static: false }) infoWindow: MapInfoWindow;
@ViewChildren(MapMarker) markers: QueryList<MapMarker>;
points: PointMap[] = [];
infoContent: string = "";
options = {
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    maxZoom: 15,
    minZoom: 6,
};

ngOnInit() {
    // points: PointMap[] array is filled up here
}

openInfoWindow(windowIndex: number, content: string) {
    this.markers.forEach((marker: MapMarker, ix: number) => {
        if (windowIndex === ix) {
            this.infoContent = content;
            this.infoWindow.open(marker);
        }
    });
}
```

My *PointMap* type (an array or list of these should come from the server side):

```
export class PointMap {
    title: string;
    position: any; // {lat, lng} object - in accordance to the API
    info: string; // HTML-formatted on server side in my case, but you may construct the content here from a number of plain string data
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<google-map [center]="center" width="100%" height="500px" [options]="options">
    <map-marker *ngFor="let marker of points; let ix = index
        [position]="marker.position" [title]="marker.title" 
        (mapClick)="openInfoWindow(ix, marker.info)">
    </map-marker>
    <map-info-window [innerHTML]="infoContent"></map-info-window>
</google-map>
```

**Believe me, this does work.**

Answer (score 2):

there is a really easy way to sort this,
looking at this call:

```
 (mapClick)="openInfoWindow(marker)"
```

can be updated to pass a variable, referene or other details possibly even the content i.e.

```
 (mapClick)="openInfoWindow(marker, reference || object || content)"
```

i.e. code I use regularly:

```
<google-map #map
                    height="90%"
                    width="100%"
                    [zoom]="zoom"
                    [center]="center"
                    [options]="options"
                    (boundsChanged)="mapBoundsChanged()"
        >
            <map-marker
                #marker="mapMarker"
                *ngFor="let location of filteredLocations"
                [position]="{lat:location.locationLatitude,lng:location.locationLongitude }"
                [title]="location.locationName"
                [icon]="env.assetsUrlBase+locationTypeMap.get(location.locationTypeId)"
                (mapClick)="openInfo(marker, location)"
            >
            </map-marker>
            <map-info-window [innerHTML]="infoContent" #infoWindow="mapInfoWindow"></map-info-window>
        </google-map>
```

This way you do not need to repeat the map or info windows and only the markers.

I would also advise that you id your children and call them in your component.ts by the id ensuring that the id in the html states their type.

This also allows for multiple maps on a single view that can behave independently.

i.e.

```
@ViewChild('map', { static: true }) map: GoogleMap;
  @ViewChild('infoWindow', { static: true }) infoWindow: MapInfoWindow
  @ViewChild('businessMap', { static: true }) businessMap: GoogleMap;
  @ViewChild('businessInfoWindow', { static: true }) businessInfoWindow: MapInfoWindow
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to modify the `openInfoWindow` function to take a string parameter, and use this string to display in the `map-info-window`.

In the component file.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MapInfoWindow, { static: false }) infoWindow: MapInfoWindow;

  infoContent: string;

  openInfo(marker: MapMarker, content: string) {
    this.infoContent = content;
    this.infoWindow.open(marker);
  }
}
```

In the template.

```
<google-map
  height="500px"
  width="100%"
  [zoom]="zoom"
  [center]="center"
  [options]="options"
  (mapClick)="click($event)"
>
  <map-marker
    #markerElem
    *ngFor="let marker of markers"
    [position]="marker.position"
    [label]="marker.label"
    [title]="marker.title"
    [options]="marker.options"
    (mapClick)="openInfo(markerElem, marker.info)"
  >
  </map-marker>

  <map-info-window>{{ infoContent }}</map-info-window>
</google-map>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I said in my original post.

Comment: They are actually different as in your original post you are not passing the extra string variable. In your `openInfoWindow` function, pass in the `place.description` variable as well. This will set the `infoContent` variable which is bound to the `map-info-window` so that it changes every time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Angular, doesn't want to display HTML code in a binding because, basically, it's a *string* binding (and for security reasons).
But, instead of :

```
<map-info-window>
        <-- this is what i'm concerned with -->
        {{ place.description }}
</map-info-window>
```

You can simply do :

```
<map-info-window [innerHTML="place.description"]>
</map-info-window>
```

However, I didn't find a way to style that (even inline CSS doesn't seem to work). But basic formatting with `<table>` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Acept two arguments on openWindow function, I define a property as MarkerLabel in my Marcador interface in order to put a label, but you can set as string with the content and a property as LatLngLiteral to use to create the marker.
Set the content using the infowindow View Child before open.

**openInfoWindow method:**

```
openInfoWindow(marker: MapMarker,markerPosition:Marcador) {
  
    this.infoWindow.infoWindow?.setContent(`${markerPosition.label.text}`)
    this.infoWindow.open(marker);
  }
```

**Map Marker:**

```
<map-marker #marker="mapMarker" *ngFor="let markerPosition of marcadores"
            [position]="markerPosition.position"
            (mapClick)="openInfoWindow(marker,markerPosition)"
           ></map-marker>
           <map-info-window></map-info-window


    export interface Marcador{
    label: google.maps.MarkerLabel,
    position: google.maps.LatLngLiteral
}
```